# What is the best way to search in different URL in React using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to develop an app to consume the Marvel API, using React with Axios.

The problem here is that I need it to search in an determined URL when nothing was typed in the input field. But when the user types something, the app should use another URL.

The problem is that the only way I got this working, was setting the **componentDidUpdate** hook. But it happens to go into an infinity loop. I think this is happening because I'm updating the state directly in this point.

So, is there a best practice to do this? Like configuring **Axios** to understand this variation, or maybe *don't mess around with componentDidUpdate*, or even *just update the state when the user click the button*?

Here's my code:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heroes: [],
      search: "",
      query: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadHeroes();
    console.log("Query state: ", this.state.query);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Query state: ", this.state.query);
  }

  loadHeroes = async () => {
    const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC;
    const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE;
    const timestamp = Number(new Date());
    const hash = md5.create();
    hash.update(timestamp + PRIVATE_KEY + PUBLIC_KEY);

    if (this.state.query === "") {
      await api
        .get(`/characters?ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`)
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results })
        );
    } else {
      await api
        .get(
          `/characters?nameStartsWith=${this.state.query}&ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`
        )
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results })
        );
    }
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    console.log("Query state updated: ", this.state.search);
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ query: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { heroes } = this.state;

    let filteredHeroes = heroes.filter(
      hero => hero.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.search}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <Wrapper>
          {filteredHeroes.map(hero => {
            return (
              <Card key={hero.id} name={hero.name} thumbnail={hero.thumbnail} />
            );
          })}
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.loadHeroes();
}
```

is that `loadHeroes()` will change `state` and that will call `componentDidUpdate` again. Which will load heroes and change `state` :). Forever.

You probably want to re-`loadHeroes()` only and only if there are changes in `state.query`. To do that use `componentDidUpdate`'s parameter `prevState`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.query != this.state.query) {
        this.loadHeroes();
    }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate